# dsquery computer with no description

Tags: batch-file, dsquery

I'm trying to make a batch script to list all laptops in my domain that doesn't have a computer description.

I can't seem to make DSQUERY find computers without descriptions
Example:

```
DSQUERY Computer -name [COMPUTERNAMES]* -desc "" -limit 0 | dsget computer -dn -desc
dsquery failed:The search filter cannot be recognized.
type dsquery /? for help.
dsget failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.
type dsget /? for help.
```

In the example above I tried to search for -desc "" which doesn't work. Do any of you have some trick to list computers without descriptions?
Grateful for every reply!

I have revised my script a bit to actually break apart the 'dsget computer -dn -desc' like this:

```
DSQUERY Computer -name LAPTOP* -limit 0 | dsget computer -dn -desc>computers_unformatted.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2,15,16,17,18,19,20 delims=,= " %%a IN (computers_unformatted.txt) DO (
    ECHO.%%a^|%%b^|%%c^|%%d^|%%e^|%%f^|%%g>>computers_unformatted2.txt
)
```

Output looks like this:

```
LAPTOP039|John|Doe|T430|Windows7|| 
LAPTOP040||||||
```

I'm onto something good here but I can't seem to write anything that makes the output become just (in the example output above) 'LAPTOP040'

Comment: Parsing the output to prove a description **is** present will also tell you the opposite.  If you can provide a sample query output **with and without** a description in your question then you might get some ideas.

Comment: I have actually thought of that. Manipulation of the output file but it comes in a strange format like this:  CN=LAPTOP011,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=ACME,OU=ONE,DC=TWO,DC=THREE    johndoe, T430, Windows 7                                            
  CN=LAPTOP_012,OU=Laptops,OU=Computers,OU=ACME,OU=ONE,DC=TWO,DC=THREE                                                                       All preceding and trailing spaces are present in the textfile that I write my DSQUERY | DSGET -statements to in my original question (just adding '>C:\TEMP\dsgetOutput.txt').

Comment: Can you paste that info in your question by editing it?  The layout is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "dsq=dsquery * dc^=acme^,dc^=one^,dc^=com -limit 0 -filter "^&^(ObjectCategory^=Computer^)^(ObjectClass^=Computer^)" -attr cn description"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('%dsq%') do ( 
  if "%%b" EQU "" echo %%a is missing a description
)
exit /b
```

**And just for fun, I whipped this up**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "dsq=dsquery * dc^=acme^,dc^=one^,dc^=com -limit 0 -filter "^&^(ObjectCategory^=Computer^)^(ObjectClass^=Computer^)" -attr cn description"
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('%dsq%') do ( 
    if "%%b" EQU "" (
    echo(%%a is missing a description
    set /p "ans=Would you like to add a description for %%a now? (Y/N) "
        if /i "!ans!" EQU "Y" ( 
          set /p "desc=Enter a new description for %%a: "
          dsadd computer "%%a" -desc !desc!
        ) ELSE (
          Echo Moving on to next computer.
        )
    )
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Matt Williamson
You've made my day!